# How to select only a border of selected area?

Tags: python, modeling, edit-mode, edges

I selected some area and I need to get selected only border of this area. Does anyone know any function to achieve that? Or a script?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Select Boundary Loop

You can find the function in the Select Menu.

It will select only the boundaries edges of the provided face selection.

As said in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#boundary-loop)'s page:

> ...based on all regions currently selected, it selects only the edges at the border(contour) of these islands.

Here's an example of usage:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for.